# Python multiprocessing: knowing the thread/CPU number

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to code a parallel code in Python using the `multiprocessing` module and I would like to know of a way to locally know which CPU is computing, but I only know of `multiprocessing.CPU_count()` to know the total CPU cores.

I'm looking for an equivalent of:

```
omp_get_thread_num()
```

in C++ openMP.

Is there such a method in Python.multiprocessing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not trivial to retrieve which CPU a process is running at (if possible at all), but if you:

- Start the same number of processes as there are CPUs available, as reported by `multiprocessing.CPU_count()`, as most applications do;
- Assume that each process will run in a distinct CPU core, as expected when using `multiprocessing` module;

Then you can "cheat" and give each process a unique *name* that will identify its CPU core! :)

```
for i in xrange(multiprocessing.CPU_count()):
    mp = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(bar,), name=i).start()
```

And then retrieve it inside the worker function spawned in the subprocess:

```
print "I'm running on CPU #%s" % multiprocessing.current_process().name
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.name):

**`multiprocessing.current_process().name`**

```
The process’s name.

The name is a string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics.
Multiple processes may be given the same name.
The initial name is set by the constructor.
```

Comment: Thank you, I had opted for a similar solution, I was passing the index `i` as an argument, or `i==0` as a boolean so only one process would have value `True` and only this process was outputting on the screen to give me progress information for example (avoiding overheading). I thought `multiprocessing` had the same variables as C++OpenMP but no, but in that case it is not too hard to circumvent this obstacle.